# Unable to show Error with self.add_error()

Tags: python, django, error-handling

I am having a problem and need your help.
I am making a django website, following information need to be verified. If it pass registration will be success and fail notice will show up. But Mean while there are no problem with success, but Notice won't show up if fail. Here are my form.py, could anyone help me? Much Thanks.

```
   if settings.VERIFY_BY_SFID and all([i in cleaned_data for i in fields]):
           number = cleaned_data["mobile_number"]
           verified =SignUpFailureAttemptService.verify_mobile_number(number)
           if not verified:
             self.add_error(None, _("Your application was rejected."))
```

Template

```
{% extends 'accounts/login_base.html' %} {% load i18n %} {% load staticfiles %} {% load semanticui %} {% load common_templatetags %} {% block welcome_text %} {% trans 'Create your personal
E-wallet account.' %} {% endblock %} {% block slogan_text %} {% trans 'Buy and sell with protection
Easy and secure to send and receive money' %} {% endblock %} {% block bigger_text %} {% blocktrans %}Already have an account?{% endblocktrans %} {% trans 'Sign in' %} {% endblock %} {% block left_content %}
STEPS:
{% include 'accounts/signup/steps.html' with active_step=step steps=5 %} 
{% block form_title %} {{ form_title }} {% endblock %} 
{% if messages %} {% for message in messages %}
{{ message }}
{% endfor %} {% endif %} 
{% block form_block %}
{% csrf_token %} {{ form.non_field_errors }} {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %} {{ hidden_field.errors }} {{ hidden_field }} {% endfor %} {% for field in form.visible_fields %} {% if field.name == 'date_of_birth' %}
{{ field.label }}*
{% endif %}
{% if field.name == 'tos' %} {% blocktrans %} I agree to {% endblocktrans %} PDS and FSG {{ field }}

{% else %} {{ field }} {% endif %}
{{ field.help_text }}
{{ field.errors }} 
{% endfor %}
{% if prev_step %} «   {% trans 'Back' %} {% endif %} 

{% if next_step_title %}
{% trans 'NEXT STEP:' %} {{ next_step_title }}
{% endif %} 
{% endblock %} {% endblock %} {% block scripts_end %} {% endblock %}
```

Comment: You need to show more context. Where is this code exactly? What does the view contain? And the template?

Comment: The Telplate base.html is like following. The code I attached above is from form.py

Comment: But *where* in the form? You should show the whole method, and probably the view too. Do you see any other errors?